# Finding angle in a triangle with one median and an isosceles triangle in it

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> In the following figure $AF=BD=DC$ and $AE=EF$. Find the angle $\alpha$.

[image]

I tried so many different things (constructing triangles, drawing parallel lines, using Ceva theorem in triangles $ABD$ and $CBE$, ...). Any help for solving this will be much appreciated.

A geomtrical solution (without trigonometry) would be very nice.

Comment: @cosmo5 is it plausible, in your mind, that there is no typo?

Comment: Its not a typo.

Comment: @cosmo5 The answer is exactly 60 degrees according to Geogebra.

Comment: @MathLover I made same mistake as you. It is AF=BD=DC not AD...

Comment: @cosmo5 thanks. I take it back :)

Comment: @dodotukoz did u find the answer for AD=BD=DC?

Comment: @Ghartal No, for $AF=BD=DC$

Comment: I'll check your solution. Thanks.

Comment: Just to let you know, there is a purely geometric solution to this problem that does not involve any trigonometry. I wrote a version of it down in the answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

In isosceles $\triangle AEF$, drop $EG \perp AF$ with $G$ on $AF$. Let $AG=GF=x$. So $BD=2x$. Let $\angle BAD = \theta$. So $AE=x\sec \theta$.

Applying Menelaus' for transversal $CE$ to $\triangle ABD$,
$$\frac{BC}{DC}\cdot\frac{DF}{FA}\cdot\frac{AE}{EB}=1$$
$$\Rightarrow DF=EB\cos \theta$$
$$\Rightarrow AD-2x=(AB-x\sec\theta)\cos \theta$$
$$\Rightarrow AD=AB\cos \theta+x$$

Next drop $BH \perp AD$ with $H$ on $AD$. In right $ABH$, $AH=AB \cos \theta$. Then $AD=AH+DH$ implies $DH=x$!

Hence in right triangle $BHD$, $BD=2x$, $HD=x=BD/2$. It turns out $\triangle BHD$ is $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$ and we conclude
$$\alpha = 60^{\circ}$$

Comment: Cool trigonometric proof. There is also a geometric proof, if you are curios.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a purely geometric proof without any trigonometry.

[image]

Draw the three lines $a, \, b, \, c$ such that:
$$A \, \in \, a \,\,\text{ and } \,\, a \, || \, BC$$
$$B \, \in \, b \,\,\text{ and } \,\, b \, || \, CA$$
$$C \, \in \, c \,\,\text{ and } \,\, c \, || \, AB$$
Furthermore, let
$$B^* \, = \, a \, \cap \, c \,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\, A^* = b \, \cap \, c$$
Then, $ABA^*C$ and $ABCB^*$  are parallelograms and furthermore
$$AB = CA^* = CB^*$$ as well as
$$AB^* = BC$$
Apply Menelaus' theorem to the triangle $BCE$ intersected by the line that passes through the collinear points $A, \, F,\, D$:
$$\frac{AB}{AE} \cdot \frac{EF}{CF} \cdot \frac{DC}{BD} = 1$$
Since by assumption $AE = EF$ and $BD = CD$, one concludes that
$$AB = CF$$
Combining this latter fact with the earlier conclusions, one observes that
$$CF = AB = CA^* = CB^*$$ which is possible if and only if triangle $\Delta \, A^*B^*F$ has $90^{\circ}$ angle at vertex $F$, i.e. $\angle \, A^*FB^* = 90^{\circ}$. But that means that:
$$\angle \, AFB^* = 180^{\circ} - \angle \, A^*FB^* = 180^{\circ} - 90^{\circ} = 90^{\circ}$$
Recall that by assumption $AF = BD = DC = \frac{1}{2}\,BC$. But by construction, $ABCB^*$ is a parallelogram and $AB^* = BC$ so
$$\Delta \, AFB^*  \, \text{ is a triangle with the properties that } \, \angle \, AFB^* = 90^{\circ} \,\, \text{ and } \,\, AF = \frac{1}{2}\, AB^* $$
which is possible if and only if $$\angle \, FAB^* = 60^{\circ}$$
However, $AB^*$ is parallel to $BC$ and consequently, by the properties of a pair of parallel lines intersected by a third line,
$$\angle \, ADB = \angle \, DAB^* = \angle \, FAB^* = 60^{\circ}$$

Comment: You are right, I got it now!  I neglected the collinear requirement and you did give a beautiful answer.  I will upvote yours and delete my answer.  Thank you for the challenge.

Comment: Nice one. You also find a $30-60-90$ triangle using construction.